# How to compile bibtex with TeXstudio?

Tags: bibtex, compiling, texstudio

I am trying to use `bibtex` for the first time. I am on windows 7, using TeXstudio. I am trying to follow the steps of [this webpage (in French)](http://www.tuteurs.ens.fr/logiciels/latex/bibtex.html).

I have created a `.bib` file, put it in the right directory and written the code in my `.tex` file. However, I do not know how to compile `bibtex` with TeXstudio (I looked around in the menus but didn't find it).

Most tutorials I found don't explain how to do it, or say to run a command, which I'm not sure how to do.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See here, **Tools Menu**

[image]

You can change the shortcut using the **Options/Configure TeXstudio...**

I'm using F10 but the default is F11.

[image]

Comment: May be if possible you could reload screenshots with default shortcuts `F11` because you say `F11` in comments and screenshot shows `F10` (I know you have changed for your convenience), may be confusing for others.

Comment: Seems the default has been changed to `F8`.

Answer (score 52):

Coming from TeXworks, I found this frustrating because I was used to being able to compile LaTeX and BibTeX all in one go. You can do this in TeXstudio, as well. If you select **Options> Configure TeXstudio...**, and select **Build** from the lefthand menu, you'll see a screen (below) that explains the default commands that are run for the various menu buttons and/or keyboard shortcuts. Now you might need to tick the box next to **Show Advanced Options** and then not untick it because it seems like there is a bug at least in version 2.10.8 of TeXstudio on Ubuntu 16.04. If you modify the **Default Compiler** option (by clicking the wrench button to the right of the text box), you'll be able to enter a series of commands to run when you compile. The screenshot below, for example, shows how to set this up to run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex` in order to resolve all cross-references.

Edit by **geras**: I suppose you could now also turn off the **Repeat contained compilation commands** button to save some time on compilation but I am not sure about it because I am a newbie.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For those who doesn't have the GUI "wrench" edit option to edit the text-boxes, you can write:

```
txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
```