# Use of .bib JabRef Reference from TeXstudio

Tags: bibtex, texstudio, jabref

Jabref generates a .bib reference file.

How can I use this in the TeXstudio?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's just a normal BibTeX database – plain text, just like TeX. Use it as you would any bib file – there is an abundance of information on the web for this (and likely here as well).

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156205/17423 help?

Answer (score 3):

JabRef provides an integration with TeXStudio, so you can push citations directly into TeXStudio. Just select TeXStudio in the toolbar as the external application and then you can push the currently selected entry as `\cite{key}` to TeXStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `bib` file in jabref.

Use one of `Cntrl`+`K` or `Cntrl`+`L` in jabref to insert the citation.
If you are using `Cntrl`+`L` be sure that corresponding editor in jabref is correctly set to TeXStudio. When using `Cntrl`+`L` the following image will help you.

[image]