# Why cannot cite .tex @phdthesis citation?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, pdftex

I'm trying to cite a phdthesis report :

```
    \documentclass[notitlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[left=0.3in,right=0.3in,top=0.3in,bottom=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\usepackage{longtable}

%\usepackage{algorithm}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{authblk} 


 \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references3.bib}

 

@phdthesis{hajjar2014cartes,
    title={Cartes auto-organisatrices pour la classification de donn{\'e}es symboliques mixtes, de donn{\'e}es de type intervalle et de donn{\'e}es discr{\'e}tis{\'e}es.},
    author={Hajjar, Chantal},
    year={2014},
    school={Sup{\'e}lec}
}

% ...........%
 \end{filecontents}
\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\par\noindent\textbf{\abstractname.}\ \ignorespaces}
{\par\medskip}


\begin{document}

\title{  title   }
\author{author1 ,\\
    ----------@gmail.com  
}

\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science,---------------------------- }


\maketitle  


\begin{abstract}
    \small
    
some text .....................
    
    
\end{abstract}

\textbf{Keywords} : global numerical optimization, mono-objective, descent gradient variants, analytic hierarchy process, \\ hybrid optimization, random search

 
\section{Problem formulation}
\cite{hajjar2014cartes}  :

 


\Floatbarrier


\newpage

 
 

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references3.bib}

\end{document}
```

Using the previous script , i got the following output :

[image]

Unfortunately , the citation isn't displayed as expected.

I hope my question is clear!

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Did you run `latex`+`bibtex`+`latex`+`latex`?

Comment: @campa , i didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: I'm using texstudio

Comment: Yes, but @campa is asking *how* you compile. TeX studio is only a specialised editor, with some facilities to compile.

Comment: @Bernard , i compile usually with F6 button ( or run symbol )

Comment: Well you should use the sequence F6+F8+F6+F6.

Comment: @Bernard , i tried the sequence many times but it doesn't worked !

Comment: What does ‘didn't work’ mean precisely? What happens?

Comment: it dipslayed Cannot find 'mouad_2.bcf'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to comment, hence I write an answer (although @Bernard already gave one in the comments):

This could help: [How to compile bibtex with TeXstudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156205/how-to-compile-bibtex-with-texstudio)

Choose the right settings in the menu shown there. In most cases the right settings are already default (then F6+F8+F6+F6 should work). But you could change the “default compiler” to include bibtex.

Comment: thank you a lot for precious help  --> problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous comments , the problem is resolved as follow :

**Options> Configure TeXstudio**

[image]

Last , press F6 to generate output :

[image]